# AppFabric Caching service crashed

Tags: caching, appfabric

We are trying to set up appfabric cache on a cluster with 6 machines.

We are getting error of type:

```
AppFabric Caching service crashed.{41b457b5000000000000000000000000 lease relationship with 32130bae000000000000000000000000 failed}
```

If we restart the cluster all 6 machines come online, then 2 but not allways the same 2 stop.

Anyone any ideas how to fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We found why this was happening.

The cluster could not be set up using the wizard due to a rights issue.

It was therefore set up by editing the config files manually. In this process some of the nodes got the same id.

Appfabric did not give an error for this, it just shut down the duplicates.